# Gnome Tweek tool will not start

Tags: gnome, python

I got allways this error if i start the tweak tool.

```bsh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 30, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.main_box.set_mode_transition_type(Handy.LeafletModeTransitionType.SLIDE)
AttributeError: 'Leaflet' object has no attribute 'set_mode_transition_type'
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04 and 20.10 same after a Update. But after Reinstall the system everything ist working